# Android HTC One Bottom Action Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, mono, xamarin.android

I’m using a HTC One (engineering sample) Android phone running Android 4.x
In any app made with Xamarin I see the action bar (red square) at the bottom of the screen. Even when having my own action bar (picture right), the bottom action bar is there. In this case, both action bars can be clicked (settings).

Some 3rd party apps have the same action bar problem, others (FaceBook etc.) don’t.

*How can I get rid of this bottom action bar?*

The sample you see here is the Xamarin ActionBarSherlock sample.

[image: Phone with Action Bar at the screen bottom]

Comment: that is not an action bar, that is the area on normal devices where the soft keys are. Since HTC loves their hard keys that area will be there. I am not sure if targeting SDK version > 11 will fix that or not because that button on the bottom is the menu button for older versions. So in short, you cant remove it and you can thank HTC for that

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get rid of this bottom action bar?

Set your `android:targetSdkVersion` to 14 or higher. What you are seeing is the "legacy menu button of shame".

I have a bit more on this topic in [this year-old blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/06/08/removing-rogue-menus.html).

Comment: Thanks for your correct answer.
Is it possible to have this button of shame removed whith a targetSdkVersion of pre-14? It would be quite annoying to have to compile my app for different phones (especially since I plan to use NineOldAndroids and target old phones as well)?

Comment: @ArthurKater I just tried this solution on a production HTC One (HTC 4.4.3) and an HTC Nexus One (Cyanogen 2.3.7). It gets rid of the useless action bar on the One and still runs on the Nexus One. In AndroidManifest.xml: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />`.